# Entity Framework IQueryable<T> Skip suddenly timing out

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I've had the following code for months and it's been working fine all along:

```
public PagedResult GetPagedData(int id, Dictionary<string, string> queryStringParameters)
{
    PagedResult pagedReturn = new PagedResult(queryStringParameters);
    IQueryable<MyData> myData = GetMyData(id, queryStringParameters);
    pagedReturn.SetPagesFromTotalItems(myData.Count());

    myData = myData.OrderByDescending(i => i.SomeDate).Skip(pagedReturn.Skip).Take(pagedReturn.PageSize);

    var list = myData.ToList(); // ***TIME OUT HAPPENS HERE***

    List<MyDataListing> listings = this._mapper.Map<List<MyDataListing>>(list);
    pagedReturn.listings = new List<IListing>(listings);

    return pagedReturn;
}
```

For some strange reason though, today I started getting a time out error on the line where I am calling ToList() (see above). The exact error is the following:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The value of pagedReturn.Skip is 0 and pagedReturn.PageSize is 500. I fixed the issue by rearranging the code like so:

```
public PagedResult GetPagedData(int id, Dictionary<string, string> queryStringParameters)
{
    PagedResult pagedReturn = new PagedResult(queryStringParameters);
    IQueryable<MyData> myData = GetMyData(id, queryStringParameters).OrderByDescending(i => i.SomeDate);
    pagedReturn.SetPagesFromTotalItems(myData.Count());

    if (pagedReturn.Skip > 0)
    {
        myData = myData.Skip(pagedReturn.Skip);
    }

    myData = myData.Take(pagedReturn.PageSize);

    var list = myData.ToList();

    List<MyDataListing> listings = this._mapper.Map<List<MyDataListing>>(list);
    pagedReturn.listings = new List<IListing>(listings);

    return pagedReturn;
}
```

What is the problem here? Why did it randomly start timing out today? That code hasn't been touched for months and, like I said above, has been working fine for months. As far as I know, nothing in the database, related to the tables in the query, has changed recently.

Comment: Did the amount of data behind increase largely ?

Comment: The query is executed by your dbms. If it's timing out, you should check the execution there. Perhaps your indexes need to be rebuild or reorganized. This can happen suddenly when the amount of data is increased. Your dbms tries to execute an optimal plan, but might determine it cannot optimize your query anymore if the amount of data grows beyond the optimization cache limit.

Comment: Check the query that EF is sending to your database, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464 ,then execute it with the execution plan and check problems.

Comment: @Antoine It has increased some, I wouldn't say it's a whole lot, but there is some increase in data. I don't know how many rows it searches through, but the result of the query only consists of 2 rows.

Comment: from how many rows at the start ? and to how many rows now ?

Comment: It can't have been lightning fast, you were probably always close to timing out. Anything can make the coin flip. More network latency, more data, updated statistics (can happen sometimes), more concurrency, or maybe a constellation of parameters that didn't occur previously. The only remedy is always to make the query faster. A good start would be to use `ProjectTo` instead of `_mapper.Map`. Maybe you need additional indexes.

Comment: The main table it searches through has increased by 522 records, up to 89536, since yesterday. One of the dependent tables has increased by 7, to 54 and another one also by 522, to 25283.

Comment: Id be betting on an ordered index on `SomeDate` like Gert says

Comment: These numbers of data are *nothing* for --what is it? Sql Server? Look at the query execution plan and follow hints for indexes to create.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, it's a SQL Server.